# Is it possible to create "Content Patches-" like Prefab Variants, but for an addressable/AssetReference?

Tags: unity-game-engine, prefab, addressables

I develop mods for a Unity Game- and that game supports Addressables, which is great. Modders can load ingame assets in order to modify them for their own purposes, then reuse them.
The problem, though, is that it has to be done procedurally, line-by-line in code. Even though the addressables can be loaded inside of the Unity Editor, changes to those instances can't be saved as their own objects.

I'd love to be able to be able to serialise some sort of object with data like:

```
class AddressableVariant {
AssetReference addressable;
Change[] changesToAddressable; }

struct Change {
SerializedProperty changedProperty;
object newValue; }
```

Is this feasible/possible? How would I even begin to go about this? I'm pretty experienced with Unity, but I'm worried that I might not be able to do this alone, especially as I've not tinkered much with GUI tracking, SerializedProperties, etc.

Any help at all is massively appreciated! I've got cold feet about starting this, but it'd be so helpful for all of my community's modders! thank you <3